# Chmod permission of specific file extension under a folder via SSH

Tags: ssh, chmod

My folder is `/images/`. There are `.png`, `.gif` and `.jpg` images in this folder. How do I change permissions of specific file extension `.jpg` to 644 under the folder via SSH?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Connect to the remote computer with ssh and then execute this command may work:

`find /images/. -name "*.jpg" | xargs chmod 644`

Comment: This won't work in a number of cases, for example if there are any spaces in any of the filenames. Use the `-exec` flag of `find` instead: `find /images/. -name "*.jpg" -exec chmod 0644 {} \;`

Comment: How can we add sudo to this command? I have to execute this with root privilege.